# AIX: Why does the timezone differ when using su or in crontab?

Tags: date, aix, timezone

```
3:root@SERVER:/root # cat wtf.sh
echo "date"
date 
echo "su - root -c date"
su - root -c date
3:root@SERVER:/root # 
3:root@SERVER:/root # ksh wtf.sh
date
Wed Nov  9 13:15:01 MEZ 2016
su - root -c date
Wed Nov  9 12:15:01 UTC 2016
3:root@SERVER:/root # grep TZ /etc/environment
    TZ=MEZ-1MESZ-2,M3.5.0/02:00,M10.5.0/03:00
3:root@SERVER:/root # oslevel -s
6100-09-06-1543
3:root@SERVER:/root #
```

Why do they differ?

Even the crontab shows UTC, but the system TZ is MEZ.

Comment: Does root have a profile that sets TZ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed TZ recently?

When you change TZ with `smitty chtz_date` it will usually advice you to reboot.

If you simply log off/on - then that session will show you the new TZ. But already running process only know of the old.

All services then needs to be restarted to catch on to the the TZ change. You cannot restart `init` hence the advice to reboot.

In your case I suspect that it will work if you kill `cron` and let it restart. This way you can avoid to reboot.

If this is not fixed via a reboot then add `echo $TZ` to see the variable in each environment you are in.

See also [How to change timezone to UTC without rebooting AIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/how-to-change-timezone-to-utc-without-rebooting-aix)

EDIT:
You check for TZ in `/etc/environment` but you should check if you override it in:

```
/etc/profile
$HOME/.kshrc
$HOME/.profile
```

Reference: [AIX Korn shell environment](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/kshrc.htm)